# Fetching token prices using Swap/v1/quote API responds wrong price on avalanche chain?

Tags: 0x, price

Using the following query and conversion for bsc and eth respectively works:

[https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=${contractAddress}&sellToken=WBNB&sellAmount=10000000000000000000](https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=$%7BcontractAddress%7D&sellToken=WBNB&sellAmount=10000000000000000000)

Price in dollars = bnb_price / data.price

---

[https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=${contractAddress}&sellToken=WETH&sellAmount=10000000000000000000](https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=$%7BcontractAddress%7D&sellToken=WETH&sellAmount=10000000000000000000)

Price in dollars = eth_price / data.price

---

Yet doing the same for the avalanche endpoint doesn't yield in the correct price:

[https://avalanche.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=${contractAddress}&sellToken=0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&sellAmount=10000000000000000000](https://avalanche.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=$%7BcontractAddress%7D&sellToken=0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&sellAmount=10000000000000000000)

Price in dollars = avax_price / data.price (WRONG)

Note: 0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee is the contract address for the native avalanche token.

Answer (score 1):

`0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee` is the contract address for native tokens for the 0x API. In this case it is the address for $AVAX, not wrapped AVAX ($WAVAX) as per the `sellToken` values of your other requests. The prices may vary slightly if you input the native token address versus the address of its wrapped version.

Please note also that the price returned by the 0x API is not denominated in USD and may not match prices displayed on sites like CoinGecko.

Could you share an example API request to the Avalanche endpoint that returns an incorrect price?